# How to automatically create 500 images with increasing numbers in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, photoshop-scripting, numbering

I want to create 500 images which all have the same size and background color but show a different number (increasing from 1 to 500). So the output should look like this:

[image]

[image]

...

[image]

Now I don't want to create all those 500 images manually. But I've read that there is a scripting mechanism in Photoshop? Is it possible to automate my task with this scripting feature and if yes, how?